# Reading text in Table Control

Tags: excel, vba, sap-erp, sap-gui

I have a problem with SAP `VA02` where I want to identify the row line in which a specific label is. In this case the label/text is "Cust. expected price".

I am trying to change the data next to this row, problem is that it is not always the same row, sometimes it is 16, 18, etc.

I am trying to find a way to loop through each row in column 2 in the structure, read the text, and find which row the label is in, then use the row as a variable to paste the price in the correct cell. I have pasted some functioning code below.

What I am doing is inputting the correct price here:
`session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTAXI_TABSTRIP_ITEM/tabpT\05/ssubSUBSCREEN_BODY:SAPLV69A:6201/tblSAPLV69ATCTRL_KONDITIONEN/txtKOMV-KBETR[3,16]").Text = Price`

My main question is how to read what text is in each cell for example `session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTAXI_TABSTRIP_ITEM/tabpT\05/ssubSUBSCREEN_BODY:SAPLV69A:6201/tblSAPLV69ATCTRL_KONDITIONEN/txtKOMV-KBETR[2,16]")`

I can probably figure out the rest from there. I haven't been able to find much regarding this specific structure, any input is appreciated. I will also post a screenshot of the page for reference. Thank you!

[image: The page in question]

```
Sub OrderRelease()

Dim Order As String
Dim RowCount As Integer
Dim Item As Integer
Dim sh As Worksheet
Dim rw As Range
Dim Sroll As Integer
Dim Price As Double

On Error Resume Next


RowCount = 0
Set sh = ActiveSheet
For Each rw In sh.Rows

  If sh.Cells(rw.Row, 6).Value = "" Then
    Exit For
  End If

  RowCount = RowCount + 1

Next rw

If Not IsObject(SAPGuiApp) Then
   Set SapGuiAuto = GetObject("SAPGUI")
   Set SAPGuiApp = SapGuiAuto.GetScriptingEngine
End If
If Not IsObject(Connection) Then
   Set Connection = SAPGuiApp.Children(0)
End If
If Not IsObject(SAP_session) Then
   Set session = Connection.Children(0)
End If
If IsObject(WScript) Then
   WScript.ConnectObject SAP_session, "on"
   WScript.ConnectObject SAPGuiApp, "on"
End If

session.findById("wnd[0]").maximize
session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/okcd").Text = "/nva02"
session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 0

For i = 2 To RowCount
    Order = Cells(i, "F")
    
    session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtVBAK-VBELN").Text = Order
    session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtVBAK-VBELN").caretPosition = 9
    session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 0
    session.findById("wnd[1]/tbar[0]/btn[0]").press
    
Continue:

    Item = Cells(i, "G") / 10 - 1
    Scroll = Item - 1
    Price = Cells(i, "H")

    Set sub = session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTAXI_TABSTRIP_OVERVIEW/tabpT\02/ssubSU" _
              & "BSCREEN_BODY:SAPMV45A:4401/subSUBSCREEN_TC:SAPMV45A:4900")
    Set tbl = sub.findById("tblSAPMV45ATCTRL_U_ERF_AUFTRAG")

    tbl.verticalScrollbar.Position = Scroll
    tbl.getAbsoluteRow(Item).Selected = True
    tbl.findById("txtVBAP-POSNR[0,8]").SetFocus
    tbl.findById("txtVBAP-POSNR[0,8]").caretPosition = 4
 
    sub.findById("subSUBSCREEN_BUTTONS:SAPMV45A:4050/btnBT_PKON").press


    Set tbl2 = session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTAXI_TABSTRIP_ITEM/tabpT\05/ssubSU" _
               & "BSCREEN_BODY:SAPLV69A:6201/tblSAPLV69ATCTRL_KONDITIONEN")

    tbl2.verticalScrollbar.Position = 8

'The below line is what I need to find. In this case, Cust. expected price would be 2,16,
'but I have not found a way to actually read the text in that cell.
    tbl2.findById("txtKOMV-KBETR[3,16]").Text = Price
    tbl2.findById("txtKOMV-KBETR[3,16]").SetFocus
    tbl2.findById("txtKOMV-KBETR[3,16]").caretPosition = 16

    session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTAXI_TABSTRIP_ITEM/tabpT\11").Select
    session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTAXI_TABSTRIP_ITEM/tabpT\11/ssubSU" _
        & "BSCREEN_BODY:SAPMV45A:4456/cmbVBAP-ABGRU").Key = " "

    session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/btn[3]").press
    session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/btnBUT2").press
    session.findById("wnd[1]/tbar[0]/btn[0]").press
    session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 0

    If Cells(i, "F") = Cells(i + 1, "F") Then
        i = i + 1
        GoTo Continue
    End If

    session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 11
    session.findById("wnd[1]/tbar[0]/btn[0]").press
    session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/btnSPOP-VAROPTION1").press

Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: I think you ask how to find the row number of a Table Control (the element name you use) where a given text is located, is that correct? NB: you might simplify the reading of your script by using a variable (two lines can be reduced to: `Set tbl = session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTAXI_TABSTRIP_OVERVIEW/tabpT\02/ssubSUBSCREEN_BODY:SAPMV45A:4401/subSUBSCREEN_TC:SAPMV45A:4900/tblSAPMV45ATCTRL_U_ERF_AUFTRAG") : tbl..verticalScrollbar.Position = Scroll : tbl.getAbsoluteRow(Item).Selected = True` ; NB: colons are used here because of Stack Overflow multiline commenting restriction)

Comment: I edited your question to make the script more legible (variable + split lines)

Comment: Yes, I am looking to find the row number where the text is located.

Answer (score 2):

You are talking about a [GuiTableControl Object](https://help.sap.com/docs/sap_gui_for_windows?q=GuiTableControl%20Object).

Display example:

[image: SAP GUI Table Control]

Here is how to refer to a value of a cell in a given row and a given column, which are both provided in variables:

```
row = 0
column = 1
cellText = session.findById(".../tblXXXXX/columnFieldName[" & column & "," & row & "]").Text
```

Another solution is to use the method GetCell on the Table Control object:

```
cellText = session.findById(".../tblXXXXX").GetCell(row,column).Text
```

NB: notice that row and column arguments are switched.

To know what values to use for **".../tblXXXXX/columnFieldName[...]**, the easiest way is to record a script, by simply moving the cursor to the desired column. The generated script will return something like that (test with the demo program `DEMO_DYNPRO_TABCONT_LOOPFLIGHTS`):

```
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tblDEMO_DYNPRO_TABCONT_LOOPFLIGHTS/ctxtDEMO_CONN-CITYFROM[2,1]").setFocus
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tblDEMO_DYNPRO_TABCONT_LOOPFLIGHTS/ctxtDEMO_CONN-CITYFROM[2,1]").caretPosition = 1
```

The **row number** corresponds to the order among the visible rows, starting from 0 (0 = first visible row). The last visible row has the number equals to the Table Control property `VisibleRowCount` minus 1. The rows which are not visible (above and below) can be accessed by making your script scroll vertically, for more information about scrolling programmatically see below chapter.

The **column number** is based on the order of columns shown in the Table Control, whatever the columns are immediately visible or visible after horizontal scrolling. The script doesn't need to perform horizontal scrolling to read the values of non-visible columns. 0 is the leftmost column, and the rightmost column has the number equals to the two properties of the Table Control `Columns.Count` minus 1.

- The list of columns and their order may vary according to the active Table Control configuration. You may wish to determine the column number based on the column name at run time, for that see below chapter.
- There may be other columns proposed via the [Table Control administrator function](https://help.sap.com/docs/SAP_NETWEAVER_AS_ABAP_752?q=Adjusting%20Table%20Controls), with the "hidden" checkbox selected. SAP GUI Scripting completely ignores these columns. If you need to work with them, you must call the table control method `ConfigureLayout` to display the administrator screen, and then you can work with the settings as you do with any other screen.

## Scrolling the rows

For a Table Control, SAP GUI Scripting knows only the data in the lines which are currently visible on the screen, because for performance reason the backend ABAP program sends only these lines to the frontend. SAP GUI Scripting can't know the values from the invisible lines. It's required that the script scrolls vertically to obtain the other rows. **Attention**, scrolling means the reloading of the whole screen, so the screen elements need to be re-instantiated. The following example scrolls the whole list to display all the values in the first column (use of the demo program `DEMO_DYNPRO_TABCONT_LOOPFLIGHTS`):

```
Set tbl = session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tblDEMO_DYNPRO_TABCONT_LOOPFLIGHTS")
' Make the first row visible (show the top of the list) -> that calls the back-end system and screen is reloaded.
' ATTENTION: when the back-end is called, to continue working with screen elements, they must be re-instantiated.
tbl.VerticalScrollbar.Position = 0

TextsOfAllCellsInColumnZero = ""
Do While True
  ' Re-instantiate the Table Control element (mandatory each time the back-end is called)
  Set tbl = session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tblDEMO_DYNPRO_TABCONT_LOOPFLIGHTS")
  visibleRow = 0
  currentScrollbarPosition = tbl.VerticalScrollbar.Position
  While visibleRow < tbl.VisibleRowCount And currentScrollbarPosition <= tbl.VerticalScrollbar.Maximum
    TextsOfAllCellsInColumnZero = TextsOfAllCellsInColumnZero & tbl.GetCell(visibleRow,0).Text & Chr(10)
    visibleRow = visibleRow + 1
    currentScrollbarPosition = currentScrollbarPosition + 1
  Wend
  If currentScrollbarPosition > tbl.VerticalScrollbar.Maximum Then
    Exit Do
  End If
  tbl.VerticalScrollbar.Position = currentScrollbarPosition
Loop
MsgBox TextsOfAllCellsInColumnZero
```

Note that this example is suitable to a small number of pages. In many other situations, there are many more pages, for an action like searching a line containing a given value, it would be much more performing to click an existing button to perform a back-end search of this value. The right page would be immediately be displayed.

## Determine the column number from the column name at run time

As explained above, the column number may vary depending on the order of columns and on hidden columns. If they vary in an undetermined way at run time, the following code allows to determine the column number based on the column name (note that the lower case prefix of the field name is to be removed, like "ctxt" in "ctxtDEMO_CONN-CITYFROM"), but it works only if there's at least 1 row (no solution found if it's needed when the Table Control is empty):

```
Set tbl = session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tblDEMO_DYNPRO_TABCONT_LOOPFLIGHTS")
column = GetColumnNumberByName(tbl,"DEMO_CONN-CITYFROM")
msgbox tbl.GetCell(row,column).text

Function GetColumnNumberByName( TableControl, ColumnName )
  If TableControl.Rows.Count > 0 Then
    For i = 0 To TableControl.Columns.Count - 1
      If TableControl.Columns(i)(0).Name = ColumnName Then
        GetColumnNumberByName = i
        Exit Function
      End If
    Next
  End If
  GetColumnNumberByName = -1
End Function
```

## Appendix

For more information, please refer to the [documentation of the "GuiTableControl Object" in the SAP Library](https://help.sap.com/docs/sap_gui_for_windows?q=GuiTableControl%20Object).

NB: if you look at other questions, be aware that a Table Control (`GuiTableControl`) is completely unrelated to a Grid View (`GuiGridView`), so don't be confused.