# SAP GUI Scripting, To find the given component number in a table and change its quantity

Tags: vba, sap-gui

In a SAP GUI transaction, I have a few columns and multiple rows, I need SAP GUI Script to go through column 1 in all the rows to find the component ID and in column 3 to change the value of the component.

SAP GUI Scripting recording does not really help as in each material there are different number of rows. Could you guys take a look at my script and guide on what needs to be changed in order to make it functional?

```vb
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTS_ITOV/tabpTCMA/ssubSUBPAGE:SAPLCSDI:0152/tblSAPLCSDITCMAT/txtRC29P-MENGE[4,0]").text = "2.400"
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTS_ITOV/tabpTCMA/ssubSUBPAGE:SAPLCSDI:0152/tblSAPLCSDITCMAT/txtRC29P-MENGE[4,0]").setFocus
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTS_ITOV/tabpTCMA/ssubSUBPAGE:SAPLCSDI:0152/tblSAPLCSDITCMAT/txtRC29P-MENGE[4,0]").caretPosition = 3
session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 0
session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/btn[11]").press
```

Comment: Please first look at how the [GuiTableControl](https://help.sap.com/viewer/product/sap_gui_for_windows/760.02/en-US?q=GuiTableControl) object works, and possibly this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68685911/reading-text-in-va02-table-control/68715008#68715008) might help for reading the values and scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

Try this !

**When you need to send a key, keep it in parenthesis**

```
session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey(0)
```

**When you need to press a button, use parenthesis too**

```
session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/btn[11]").press()
```

For more information, read this [SendVkey](https://rpaframework.org/libdoc/RPA_SAP.html#Send%20Vkey)

Comment: Welcome to SO! Try to use the code tag {} for code (CTRL-K), like `session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey(0)`.