# VBA run time error "614" while looping through SAP table

Tags: excel, vba, sap-gui

While looping through an SAP table, I get the run time error 614 "The enumerator of the collection cannot find en element with the specified index", when I reach a blank row.

Using the Rowcount method does not get me the the correct amount of non-blank rows. Any ideas on how I can get rid of the error or get another way to loop through only non-blank rows?

```
 Sub Process1
        Dim SAP_table1 AS Object
        Dim RowAmount As Integer
    

// Specifying SAP table

   RowAmount = SAP_table1.RowCount // Does not return the correct amount of non-blank rows

    Do While SAP_table1.Columns.Item(1).ElementAt(J).DisplayedText <> ""   // I get the run time error 614 here when I reach a blank cell
    
       // Do something
        J = J + 1
    
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: I think you have to use `RowCount  - 1`

Comment: The RowCount is giving me 33 while the amount of non-blank rows is 5. So I don't think this will help.

Comment: Maybe I was not concise enough. If you loop through a table with number of rows `rowcount` you have to stop at `rowcount - 1`. Otherwise you will run into an error. Your loop condition does not do that.  Your code will possibly also not work in case the number `rowcount` is bigger than number of `VisibleRowCount`. It seems that this is right now not the case for you but it could be.  [Reading material](https://help.sap.com/docs/sap_gui_for_windows/b47d018c3b9b45e897faf66a6c0885a8/ce1d9e64355d49568e5def5271aea2db.html?version=760.03&locale=en-US)

Comment: Addtional [reading material](https://tricktresor.de/wp-content/downloads/StSchnell_ReadTableWithSAPGUIScripting.pdf) , unfortunately only in German but maybe it helps

Comment: I changed the loop to " For J = 0  To SAP_table1.RowCount -1 " and it still gives me an error when a blank row is reached. The same happens if I use " For J = 0  To SAP_table1.VisibleRowCount -1 "

Comment: MO you now need to edit your post in order to give more details. Which transaction ? Or ist is SE16 with which table? It's also a good idea to add your try with the `for` loop

Comment: And you need to indicate that we're talking about a `GuiTableControl` object, to not confuse with `GuidGridView` object. Note that you must scroll to reach non-visible rows, and you must reinstantiate your variables. See my answer [how it works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68685911/reading-text-in-va02-table-control).