# Trouble looping through SAP table to bring the next empty row in to view as the 1st row visible

Tags: sap-gui

I am trying to loop through my table in SAP which contains a dynamic number of entries.

I have previously tried using a rowcount +1 approach but the table has a random amount of empty rows at the end of the table that get included in the count.

Everything is working except the loop as it always fails to iterate past the first row.

Only 14 rows are ever in view as seen here...

[image]

```
On Error Resume Next

Dim sapTable As Object
Dim rowIndex As Integer
Dim isEmptyRow As Boolean

session.FindById("wnd[0]/usr/cntlIMAGE_CONTAINER/shellcont/shell/shellcont[0]/shell").DoubleClickNode "F00018"

session.FindById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtRC271-PLNNR").Text = "C061SL01"

session.FindById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtRC271-WERKS").Text = ""

session.FindById("wnd[0]/usr/txtRC271-PLNAL").Text = ""

session.FindById("wnd[0]/usr/txtRC271-PLNAL").SetFocus

session.FindById("wnd[0]/usr/txtRC271-PLNAL").CaretPosition = 0

session.FindById("wnd[0]/tbar[1]/btn[6]").Press

session.FindById("wnd[0]/tbar[1]/btn[31]").Press

Set sapTable = session.FindById("wnd[1]/usr/tblSAPLCZDITCTRL_4010")

isEmptyRow = False
rowIndex = 0

While Not isEmptyRow
    If sapTable.GetCellValue(rowIndex, "MATERIAL") = "" Then
        isEmptyRow = True
    Else
        rowIndex = rowIndex + 1
    End If
Wend

session.FindById("wnd[1]/usr/tblSAPLCZDITCTRL_4010").verticalScrollbar.Position = rowIndex

session.FindById("wnd[1]").SendVKey 0
```

The goal is to be able to use the following to input new values in to the empty row once in view (Not sure if this will work but it was pulled from a recorded macro so should work).

```
session.FindById("wnd[1]/usr/tblSAPLCZDITCTRL_4010/txtMAPL-PLNAL[0,1]").Text = "1"

session.FindById("wnd[1]/usr/tblSAPLCZDITCTRL_4010/txtMAPL-MATNR[2,1]").Text = fert

session.FindById("wnd[1]/usr/tblSAPLCZDITCTRL_4010/txtMAPL-WERKS[3,1]").Text = "C061"
```

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This GUI element is a `GuiTableControl` object. You need to scroll the lines. This detailed answer explains how it works and what can be done: [Reading text in Table Control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68685911/reading-text-in-table-control)